# How to: Threading on windows platform (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-xp

I shall like to know how to use threading on windows platform. Do I need to include some lib or dll file? Is there some command?

Answer (score 6):

I'd use [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread.html), with which you gain portability as well as ease of use.

Answer (score 4):

The Windows API (Win32) includes a number of threading tools.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684852%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Since you tagged this as C++ and not C, you might however consider using something more elaborate like [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/) (or std::thread if your compiler supports it) or [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread.html) like usta suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Use the general CRT/ Windows API handles & functions ([_beginthread, _beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28VS.71%29.aspx), etc.) or MFC classes, like [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/threads_and_mfc.aspx).

Comment: <nitpick>Actually `_beginthread*` aren't WinAPI, but they are a part of the CRT. They should be used instead of CreateThread & co. to have the CRT init correctly its data structures for the new thread.</nitpick>

Answer (score 1):

for documentation regarding C++ 0x threads standard that is also portable (works on any platform) you can also have a lokk here: http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/overload93.pdf (see article multi-threading in C++0x)